# Draw a box around each element of the xy-pic

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

How could I draw lines (like those in a tabular environment drawn by `\hline` and `|c|c|c|` in the following code?

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \xymatrix{
        x_0 \ar[dr]    & x_1 \ar[d] \ar[dr] & x_2 \ar[d]   \\
        % 
        \sum(x_0..x_0) & \sum(x_0..x_1)     & \sum(x_1..x_2)\\
    }
}
```

For some reason, I can't compile the document if I use `*F{argument}` in order to draw a box around each element.

To make more clear who ideally the output would be:

```
\begin{tabular}{| c| c| c|}
    \hline
    x_0& x_1& x_2\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

followed by the arrows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please provide a minimal example. You have to use the syntax:
`*+[F]{<argument>}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xypic,xypdf}
\begin{document}
\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \xymatrix{
        *+[F]{x_0} \ar[dr]    & x_1 \ar[d] \ar[dr] & x_2 \ar[d]   \\
        % 
        \sum(x_0..x_0) & \sum(x_0..x_1)     & \sum(x_1..x_2)\\
    }
}
\end{document}
```

You can set the frame global:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xypic,xypdf}
\begin{document}
\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\entrymodifiers={++[F]}
    \xymatrix{
        x_0 \ar[dr]    & x_1 \ar[d] \ar[dr] & x_2 \ar[d]   \\
        % 
        \sum(x_0..x_0) & \sum(x_0..x_1)     & \sum(x_1..x_2)\\
    }
}
\end{document}
```

[image]